# Laravel database relationship in migration vs in class - Confused - Both of them are need?

Tags: laravel, migration, relationship

I am confused about Laravel database relationship (unsigned id, foreign references, cascade).

Do I have to use relationship in class (like hasMany, hasOne) and in table migration (like foreign, references); for both of them too?

I had read some articles but they are not clear for me. what is the best way for best developing on an example?

As an example for category and blog post; how should it be or your best example please?

**create_categories_table migration:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**create_posts_table migration:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**and Post Model:**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The role of migrations is to build your database schema (INSERT TABLE, ALTER TABLE, FOREIGN KEYS, DROP COLUMN, etc...).

The role of relations in Eloquent Model is to make Model aware of relations with other models. It provides a convenient way to query related models.
Relations will not create foreign keys for you.

For example if a post can be in only one category and a category contains many posts :

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}
```

Then, in your Post model :

```php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

If you need you can also add this to Category Model :

```php
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

This will allow you to easily retrieve all posts of a category for example :

```php
    public function getPostsByCategory(int $categoryId) 
    {
        $posts = Category::find($categoryId)->posts()->get();

        return $posts;
    }
```

EDIT :
I think the main interest is when you want to eager load relations.
For example you have posts in a blog.
Each post have many categories. (a post can be in many categories).
Each category have many posts.
Each post have many comments

In homepage I want to display last 5 posts with for each post their categories and comments.

If I build well designed relations, I can do this:

```php
public function getLatestPosts()
{
    return Post::query()
        ->with(['categories', 'comments'])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();
}
```

It will get last 5 posts and it will attach categories and comments to each Post model.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
why don't many laravel developers use database relation? even in tutorials. at least i haven't seen it. if it is possible, could you share a good example for database relationship on Laravel example?

Comment: I just edited my answer so you can find a usefull example

Answer (score 1):

Technically you don't have to define relationships between related data in your database, however, it is good practice to do so and provides benefits such as [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) and [cascading](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44962/212803). There are also tools that can reverse engineer your database to generate a visual representation of its structure including relationships if they have been defined.

Adding relationships in your migration files creates that relationship at the database level, informing the engine that there is a logical relationship between data. You can define a foreign key constraint in your migrations in many ways, however, as of Laravel `7.x` there is a [`forieignId`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_foreignId) method and a [`constrained`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/ForeignIdColumnDefinition.html#method_constrained) method providing a simplified way of defining relationships from the previous method.

So for a basic example, to define a simple `one-to-one` relationship you might do:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('child', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('parent_id')->constrained();
    });
}
```

Similarly, using [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships) to define relationships at the application level is not required. However, these helper methods provide a consistent and simplified implementation for managing related data that would otherwise require you to write additional code.

At least one but ideally both of the above would be used.

**Update**

> if we need set a foreign key as a different key the using is just like
> ->constrained('privateName_categories'). two basic questions: * how Laravel understands that the reference table is 'categories' on your
> example without writing its name?

The argument provided to `constrained` is not the name of the foreign key field but the name of the table the foreign key references. This is used in instances that either your foreign key or the table it references differ from the standard Laravel naming conventions and therefore cannot be inferred.

Laravel uses naming conventions to make connections between things. For foreign keys that convention has the format `{table}_{id}`. Laravel inspects the foreign key name and then uses the `{table}` element of the convention to create the relationship behind the scenes. If you're not using conventions you need to inform Laravel.

The following uses conventions to automatically create a relationship between the `posts` and `categories` table based on the value of the `foreignId` method argument.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
    });
}
```

This example doesn't use a standard foreign key naming convention and so the related table needs to be provided to `constrained`.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('another_field')->constrained('categories');
    });
}
```

Similarly, for scenarios in that you're not using conventions, you might need to specify the related column names in your Eloquent Model relationship. The exact syntax for this differs based on the type of relationship (`hasOne`, `hasMany`, `manyToMany`, etc.). You can read up on the different syntaxes for each relationship in Laravels [defining relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) documentation.

> you mention about reverse engineering tools

[DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) by JetBrains can inspect the schema of your database and produce a visual representation. Others are also available, just do a search of the internet.

Comment: I saw it, as a short and upgraded using. also if we need set a foreign key as a different key the using is just like     **->constrained('privateName_categories')**.

two basic questions:
 * how Laravel understands that the reference table is 'categories' on your example without writing its name?
 * and you mention about reverse engineering tools; could you share a few of them please. I want to try them for testing. 

thank you!

Comment: @JackUK I have updated my answer to address your additional questions.

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel, it's not strictly required to define a foreign key column in your migration when developing relationships between tables. However, it's highly recommended to define foreign key constraints in your migrations for several reasons:

1. **Data Integrity**: Foreign key constraints ensure that the data in your database remains consistent and valid. They enforce referential integrity by preventing the creation of orphaned records (i.e., child records without a corresponding parent record).
2. **Relationship Clarity**: Defining foreign key constraints in your migrations makes the relationships between your tables explicit and clear. Other developers (including your future self) can easily understand the relationships just by looking at the migration files.
3. **Performance Optimization**: Foreign key constraints can improve the performance of your database queries, especially when you're performing joins or cascading operations. They allow the database engine to optimize query execution plans.
4. **Database-level Validation**: Foreign key constraints provide an additional layer of validation at the database level. They prevent invalid data from being inserted or updated in the database, even if your application logic has bugs or vulnerabilities.

To define a foreign key constraint in your migration, you can use the `foreignId()` method provided by Laravel's Schema Builder. For example:

```php
Schema::table('child_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('parent_id')->constrained('parent_table');
});
```

This creates a foreign key column named `parent_id` in the `child_table`, which references the `id` column in the `parent_table`. The `constrained()` method specifies the referenced table.

In summary, while it's not strictly required to define foreign key constraints in your migrations, it's a recommended best practice for maintaining data integrity, improving clarity, optimizing performance, and providing additional validation at the database level.